# Memory usage of sparse matrices (scipy)

Tags: python, scipy, memory-profiling

I was expecting `scipy`'s sparse matrices to use a lot less memory than the na(t)ive list of lists representation, but experiments have proven me wrong. In the snippet below, I'm building a random binary matrix with around 75% zeroes, and then comparing the memory usage with each available representation in `scipy.sparse` (simplified IPython session):

```
# %load_ext memory_profiler, from scipy import sparse, etc.
# ...
%memit M = random_binary_matrix(5000, 5000)  # contains ints
peak memory: 250.36 MiB, increment: 191.77 MiB

In : sum(line.count(0) for line in M) / (len(M) * len(M[0]))
Out: 0.75004468

%memit X_1 = sparse.bsr_matrix(M)
peak memory: 640.49 MiB, increment: 353.76 MiB
%memit X_2 = sparse.coo_matrix(M)
peak memory: 640.71 MiB, increment: 286.09 MiB
%memit X_3 = sparse.csc_matrix(M)
peak memory: 807.51 MiB, increment: 357.53 MiB
%memit X_4 = sparse.csr_matrix(M)
peak memory: 840.04 MiB, increment: 270.91 MiB
%memit X_5 = sparse.dia_matrix(M)
peak memory: 1075.20 MiB, increment: 386.87 MiB
%memit X_6 = sparse.dok_matrix(M)
peak memory: 3059.86 MiB, increment: 1990.62 MiB
%memit X_7 = sparse.lil_matrix(M)
peak memory: 2774.67 MiB, increment: 385.39 MiB
```

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something (including the point of these alternative representations)?

... or is `memory_profiler`, or my lack of comprehension thereof, to blame? In particular, the relationship between "peak memory" and "increment" seems dubious at times: initialising `X_2` supposedly increments memory usage by 286.09 MiB, yet the peak memory usage is barely above what it was prior to executing that line.

If it matters: I'm running Debian 12, Python 3.11.2, IPython 8.5.0, scipy 1.10.1, memory_profiler 0.61.0

Comment: It seems like you are putting a fully populated dense matrix in a sparse format. You probably want something like [`eliminate_zeros`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.bsr_matrix.eliminate_zeros.html#scipy.sparse.bsr_matrix.eliminate_zeros) on your sparse matrix or build it differently

Comment: For each format, read how the data is stored.  `coo` for example is 3 arrays, each the length of the number of nonzero terms.  `csr` replaces one of those with an array the length of the row dimension. `dok` is a `dict`.  `lil` is 2 object dtype arrays.  `bsr` shouldn't be better than csr with 'random' data.

Comment: Another approach is to use `sparse.random` to make `coo` with specified density.  Conert that to other formats with the `tocsr` etc methods, and to dense with `toarray`.  For large very sparse matrices, the dense equivalent often results in a memory error.

Comment: besides memory, consider calculation times.  I use a 5% sparsity rule of thumb.

Comment: What's the dtype of your `M`?  `int`, `float`?  Are there true 0s, or just values close to 0?

Comment: @hpaulj: I don't use `numpy`, `M` is a simple `list` of `list`s of `int`.

Comment: So each constructor will make temporary numpy array, using `5000*5000*8=200MiB` of memory..  I don't think any works directly from a lisi of list. Most (if not all) first make a coo, and convert that.

Comment: Good point, I'll try to convert them from a numpy array.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a sparse matrix from a dense matrix results in a fully populated sparse matrix (including explicit zeros). This is because scipy doesn't know the tolerance that you want to use for excluding values close to zero. Arguably, it should come with a factory method that does this for you, but we can always build one manually.

The sparse matrices come with many different combinations of constructor arguments. It seems that you want to exclude only explicit zeros. For this, something like this should work fine:

```py
nonzeros = M.nonzero()
# argument pattern csr_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind)), [shape=(M, N)])
X_4 = sparse.csr_matrix((M[nonzeros], nonzeros), M.shape)
```

With other tolerances you could use this:

```py
tolerance = 0.1
nonzeros = (abs(M) > tolerance).nonzero()
X_4 = sparse.csr_matrix((M[nonzeros], nonzeros), M.shape)
```

You can also create a fully populated sparse matrix first and then call [`eliminate_zeros()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.eliminate_zeros.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.eliminate_zeros) on it but this will result in temporarily higher memory usage.

Comment: The `repr` display of each format shows the the shape and number of nonzeros.  Constructing a sparse matrix from dense can push peak usage above final.  Most formats first go through `coo` which has to sort coordinates.

Comment: If the input is an int dtype tolerances shouldn't be an issue.  A zero is a zero and won't be in the sparse representation.

Comment: @hpaulj confirmed. But then what's the issue with OP's `csr_matrix` constructor? By my calculation his increment should be about 50 MiB

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I wasn't aware of `eliminate_zeros()` or the need to call it. If I use it on `X_1` in my example after building the matrix, I free approximately 250 MiB. So it must use around 110 MiB, which is better than `M` but still not so impressive. Maybe I was expecting too much.

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre I assume it's just the memory allocator not releasing all memory back to the OS or something pooling allocations. I haven't done the math for BSR but CSR format should have 8 byte per row plus 8 byte per nonzero entry plus the nonzero payload. So the memory usage should be lower

Comment: I think `elminate_zeros` is only needed if you tweak values of an existing csr, such as setting some nonzeros to zero.  csr does not automatically prune its sparsity in such cases.  It shouldn't been needed when creating an matrix from dense (with true 0s) or other formats.  Note also that csr complains if you try to 'add' nonzero values.

Answer (score 1):

Without adding `memit` and working with a much smaller dimension, here's a coo matrix:

```
In [60]: M = sparse.random(10,10, .25, 'coo').astype(bool).astype(int)
In [61]: M
Out[61]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 25 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Its dense equivalent:

```
In [62]: M.A
Out[62]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
In [63]: np.count_nonzero(M.A)
Out[63]: 25
In [64]: M.A.nbytes
Out[64]: 800
```

Memory use of the main arrays - with data and coordinates:

```
In [65]: M.data.nbytes+M.row.nbytes+M.col.nbytes
Out[65]: 400
```

Converting to csr can reduce memory use by replacing the `M.row` with `indptr`.  I say can, since that depends on the shape.  Same for csc.

```
In [66]: Mr=M.tocsr()
In [67]: Mr.data.nbytes+Mr.indptr.nbytes+Mr.indices.nbytes
Out[67]: 344
```

For a 'ranndom' matrix, `bsr` does not help:

```
In [68]: Mb = M.tobsr()
In [69]: Mb
Out[69]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 25 stored elements (blocksize = 1x1) in Block Sparse Row format>
```

Memory of a lil is harder to estimate, since it stores the info in object dtype arrays, as lists:

```
In [70]: Mi = M.tolil()
In [72]: Mi.data, Mi.rows
Out[72]: 
(array([list([1, 1]), list([1, 1]), list([1, 1]), list([1]),
        list([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), list([1, 1]), list([1, 1, 1, 1]),
        list([1, 1]), list([1, 1, 1, 1]), list([])], dtype=object),
 array([list([1, 7]), list([8, 9]), list([3, 8]), list([8]),
        list([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]), list([0, 2]), list([1, 2, 3, 5]),
        list([0, 6]), list([0, 3, 6, 7]), list([])], dtype=object))
```

`dok` is a dict:

```
In [73]: Md =M.todok()
In [74]: Md.keys()
Out[74]: dict_keys([(0, 1), (0, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (2, 3), (2, 8), (3, 8), (4, 0), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 9), (5, 0), (5, 2), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 5), (7, 0), (7, 6), (8, 0), (8, 3), (8, 6), (8, 7)])
```

None of this considers memory use during the conversions.  Going from dense to coo requires a `nonzero` call to get all the nonzero coordinates.  Making a coo from the data/row/col inputs may not add any memory use if those arrays are the correct types.  Making a csr from coo may require lexical sorting of the coordinates.  Most math is done in the csr format, so there can be a lot of hidden conversion between formats. lil and dok are good for iterative inputs, but otherwise slow and more memory intensive.